# Mathematical induction:Split a pile of stones

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Suppose you begin with a pile of n stones and split this pile into n
>   piles of one stone each by successively splitting a pile of stones
>   into two smaller piles. Each time you split a pile you multiply the
>   number of stones in each of the two smaller piles you form, so that if
>   these piles have $r$ and $s$ stones in them, respectively, you compute $r*s$.
>   Show that no matter how you split the piles, the sum of the products
>   computed at each step equals $n(n − 1)/2$

This is an example in strong induction section.
But I think this can be done just use mathematical induction, right?

Basic Step: It's true for $n=2$.

Inductive Step: Assume that it's true for n=k, show that it's also true for n=k+1:

If we have k+1 stones, it can be split into two small piles, $r=k$, $s=1$, we have $r*s=k$, this is one part of our sum, and the rest k stones equals  $k(k − 1)/2$, then add k to it, $ k + \frac{k(k − 1)}{2}= \frac{2k}{2} + \frac{k(k − 1)}{2} = \frac{2k+k^2-k}{2} = \frac{k^2+k}{2} = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

It's also true for n=k+1.

We proved that it's correct using mathematical induction.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong: You can split your $k+1$ stones in various ways into smaller piles of sizes $r$ and $s$. You only considered one particular splitting.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956165/a-problem-about-the-pile-splitting-problem and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983566/proof-that-when-repeatedly-splitting-a-heap-of-marbles-into-two-and-writing-down and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115105/fascinating-induction-problem-with-numerous-interpretations

Comment: I don't understand, I can always split it in this way, and I can always have same result, also it didn't say which split way must be used, right?

Comment: @Ned: That’s precisely the point: the rules allow every possible splitting of the stack, so your argument has to work for every possible splitting, not just for one that you happened to single out.